# Freemarker #include ignore-missing .... i think i miss something

Tags: java, servlets, freemarker, template-engine

I'm a complete newbie with freemarker, so i'm sure that i miss something!!

I'm building a website using tomcat and java servlet, so I need freemarker to build html code.
I want to include sometimes a template into another as in the code

template1.ftl

```
<section>
    <header class='title'>Wrapper</header>
    <#include dynamicOptionalContent>
    <section>this is my static content</section>
</section>
```

template2.ftl

```
<section>
    <p>this section sometimes have to be shown sometimes not</p>
</section>
```

everything works fine if I process the template1 with a data-model as in the code

```
SimpleHash myData=new SimpleHash();
myData.put("dynamicOptionalContent","path/to/ftl/template2.ftl");
```

but if i don't provide any *dynamicOptionalContent* everything fails because freemarker wants a valid path to a template, more in general, it looks for an entry *dynamicOptionalContent* ... but sometimes i don't want to provide it!

any ideas?

actually i've found an option to use on the tag <#include> as in the code

```
<#include dynamicOptionaContent ignore-missing=true>
```

but it still fails and raise an exception

please help!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you try `<#if dynamicOptionalContent?has_content><#include .vars['dynamicOptionalContent']></#if>` ?

Comment: @sev No need for `.vars`. Variables are always resolved on run time after all.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `#include` is irrelevant here. FreeMarker won't allow you to refer to a missing value anywhere, unless you provide a default value for it (`myOptionalVar!'my default'`), or unless you want to test it if it exists (`myOptionalVar??`). So if you don't want to do the inclusion if the variable is missing, then:

```
<#if dynamicOptionalContent??><#include dynamicOptionalContent></#if>
```

The `ignore_missing` option of `#include` is a different mater. It deals with the situation when the *template* (the file) referred is missing.